# Pass additional arguments to the callback function in Celery chord

Tags: python, python-2.7, callback, celery, chord

I need to pass additional arguments to my callback function in celery chords. (**Celery version : 4.1.0 (latentcall) and Python 2.7**)

Consider the below sample:

**program.py**

```
from tasks import get_stock_info, call_back
from celery import group, chord

def chord_queue():
    header = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 5, 4])
    callback = call_back.subtask()
    header1 = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 4, 4])
    res = chord(header,queue='susanoo_dev')(callback)
    res1 = chord(header1,queue='susanoo_core')(callback)
    print(res.get())
    print(res1.get())
    print("We are done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chord_queue()
```

**tasks.py**

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from celery_app import app
import time

@app.task
def get_stock_info(delay):
    print('hello Celery--------')
    time.sleep(delay)
    print('Whats up')
    return 10

@app.task
def call_back(num):
    print("Everything is done------")
    print("Everything is done------")
    return sum(num)
```

**celery_app.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://my_user:my_pass@localhost/my_vhost', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

CELERY_CONFIG = {
    'CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE': 'default',
    'CELERY_QUEUES': (Queue('dev'), Queue('core'),)
}

app.conf.update(**CELERY_CONFIG)
```

Now in this case, when the chord gets called and after all the 3 *get_stock_info* tasks are done, the *call_back* gets called, to which the value *10*, which is the return value from the *get_stock_info* gets passed automatically. 
Now along with the return values I would also want to pass an additional argument say a string as "abcd" to the callback function.

How do I do it ?

I have already tried doing this as suggested on some blogs/SO answers etc.

**program.py**

```
def chord_queue():
    header = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 5, 4])
    callback = call_back.subtask(kwargs={'my_str' : 'abcd'})
    header1 = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 4, 4])
    res = chord(header,queue='susanoo_dev' )(callback)
    res1 = chord(header1,queue='susanoo_core')(callback)
    print(res.get())
    print(res1.get())
    print("We are done")
```

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task
def call_back(num, my_str):
    print("Everything is done------")
    print("Everything is done------")
    print my_str
    return my_str, sum(num)
```

But this does not seem to work and throws the following error:

> celery.backends.base.ChordError: Callback error: TypeError("call_back() got an unexpected keyword argument 'my_str'",)

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer. Thanks to a friend who helped me out with it. 
All that was being done wrong in the above solution was to not define `my_str` as a keyword argument in the definition of the `call_back()`.

So the working solution would be:

**program.py**

```
def chord_queue():
    header = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 5, 4])
    callback = call_back.subtask(kwargs={'my_str' : 'abcd'})
    header1 = (get_stock_info.subtask((delay,)) for delay in [4, 4, 4])
    res = chord(header,queue='susanoo_dev' )(callback)
    res1 = chord(header1,queue='susanoo_core')(callback)
    print(res.get())
    print(res1.get())
    print("We are done")
```

**task.py**

```
@app.task
def call_back(num, my_str=None):
    print("Everything is done------")
    print("Everything is done------")
    print my_str
    return my_str, sum(num)
```

And it works as expected without any issues.